# From the model, how I can access the data retrieved in the view?

Tags: component, development, model

I'm trying to add some external information to a component, and it retrieves the data in `view.html.php`.  Once it is retrieved, how can I use it the model?  I've tried as many of the usual variables that I can think of, but no success.  I can see that it's buried down inside `$this` (which is an extension of `JModelAdmin`), but can find a way to get to it.

example\view.html.php

```
public function display($tpl = null) {
    $this->state    = $this->get('State');
    $this->item     = $this->get('Item');
    $this->form     = $this->get('Form');
    $this->MyInfo   = $this->get(MyInfo);  // Use $this->item to get my info
```

models\example.php:

```
public function getItem($pk = null) {
    if (!$item = parent::getItem($pk))
    {
        throw new Exception('Failed to load item');
    }
    return $item;
}

public function getMyInfo($pk = null)
{
    // Need some of the data from `$this->item` already retrieved in function `display`
    // Do some SQL here

    return $mydata;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the parent from your get function

```
public function getMyInfo($pk = null)
{
   $myItem = parent::getItem($pk);
   echo $myItem->myfieldname;
   .
   .
   .
```