# Access Model State Variable in View

Tags: joomla-3.x, view

This might a simple question, I've Model State variable set in my Model. When I "print_r" it in view. It provides following output:

```
JObject Object
(
    [_errors:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [task] => 
    [request.id] => 3
    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [path] => /media/com_helpdesk/files/
                )

            [separator] => .
        )

)
```

I can access 'task', 'params' variable in my view.html.php as follows:

```
echo $this->get('State')->params
```

my question is, How can I access "request.id" variable in similar way.

i.e. `echo $this->get('State')->request.id`

Above is (of course) not working due to additional ". (dot)".

Please note that this question is not duplicate of [From the model, how I can access the data retrieved in the view?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/from-the-model-how-i-can-access-the-data-retrieved-in-the-view) as I am trying to print variable with "dot" operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use get function of the state object (object of JObject class)

```
$state = $this->get('State');
$requestId = $state->get('request.id', 0);
```

second parameter is default value to return in case no value exist in state object with given first parameter.